# How to reset Validation Errors displayed on jsp page on pressing reset button

Tags: javascript, jsp

**Hello when i get some validation error if i reset my form the errors remain on the page how can i reset the errors as well with input fields. Please help me on this**

**am new to javascript what should i write in resetForm() method??**

```
<form action="RegisterServlet" method="post" name="Register" id="signup" onSubmit="return  validate()">
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtFname" id="fname" maxlength="30" onKeyup="capitalize(this)"/><br/>
<span  id="errorFirstNameMissing" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide your first name.</font></span>
<span  id="errorFirstNameInValid" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid first name.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtLname" id="lname" maxlength="30" onKeyup="capitalize(this)"/><br/>
<span id="errorLastNameMissing" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide your Last name.</font></span>
<span id="errorLastNameInValid" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid Last name.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gender* : </td>
<td><select name = "txtGender" id="gender">
<option value="unknown">Select your Gender</option>
<option value="Male">Male</option>
<option value="Female">Female</option>
</select><br/>
<span id="errorMissingGender" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please select a Gender.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Category* : </td>
<td><select name = "txtCategory" id="category">
<option value="unknown">Select your Category</option>
<option value="Affiliate">Affiliate</option>
<option value="Client">Client</option>
<option value="Admin">Admin</option>
</select><br/>
<span id="errorMissingCategory" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please select a Category.</font></span>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><script type="text/javascript"
src="js/Calendar.js"></script>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Age :</td>
<td><input type=text name=txtAge id="ageId" readonly  style="width: 20px;background-color:#D0D0D0;border:none"/>yrs.</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address* : </td>
<td><textarea rows="5" name="txtAddr" id="addr" cols="30"></textarea><br/>
<span id="errorMissingAddress" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid Address.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>State* :</td>  
<td> <select onchange="print_city('city',this.selectedIndex);" id="state" name ="txtState"></select><br/>
<span id="errorMissingState" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please select a state.</font></span>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City* :</td> <td><select name ="txtCity" id ="city"></select>
        <script language="javascript">print_state("state");</script><br/>
<span id="errorMissingCity" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please select a city.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Pincode* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtPin" id="pin"/><br/>
<span id="errorMissingPinCode" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide your Pincode.</font></span>
<span id="errorPinCodeInvalid" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid Pincode.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>e-Mail* : </td>
<td><input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="email"/><br/>
<span id="errorMissingEmail" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide your emailId.</font></span>
<span id="errorEmailInvalid" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid emailId.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Contact Number : </td>
<td><input type="text"  name="txtStd" id="std" maxlength="6" style="width: 40px"/>-<input type="text" name="txtPhone" id="phone" maxlength="8"/><br/>
<span id="errorStdCodeInvalid" style="visibility:hidden;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid std code.</font></span>
<span id="errorPhoneNoInvalid" style="visibility:hidden;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid contact no.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Mobile Number* : </td>
<td>+91-<input type="text" name="txtMobile" id="mobile" maxlength="10"/><br/>
<span id="errorMissingMobileNo" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide your mobile number.</font></span>
<span id="errorMobileNoInvalid" style="display:none;"><font color="red">*Please provide a valid mobile number.</font></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<p><font color="red">Note: All the fields marked with * are mandatory.</font></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="chkAgree" onclick="EnableSubmit(this)" /><font color="green"> I here by declare that the above data entered by me is true to my knowledge.</font> </p>
<br/>

<div class="style2">
<table>
<tr>
<td><button type="submit" id="submit" disabled style="width: 80px;height: 40px">Submit</button></td>
<td><div class="divider"></div></td>
<td><button type="reset" style="width: 80px;height: 40px" onClick="resetForm()">Reset</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it by adding this into function resetForm()

```
function resetForm(){
document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorLastNameMissing').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorLastNameInValid').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorMissingCategory').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorMissingGender').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorMissingDOB').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorDateInvalid').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorMissingAddress').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorMissingState').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorMissingCity').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorMissingPinCode').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorPinCodeInvalid').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorMissingEmail').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorEmailInvalid').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorStdCodeInvalid').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorPhoneNoInvalid').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorMissingMobileNo').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('errorMobileNoInvalid').style.display='none';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I HAD THE SAME PROBLEM !!! I ADDED THIS FUNCTION AND IT WORKED FINE FOR ME.

```
 function resetForm(){
 document.getElementById('errorFirstNameMissing').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorFirstNameInValid').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorLastNameMissing').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorLastNameInValid').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorMissingCategory').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorMissingGender').innerHTML=""
 document.getElementById('errorMissingDOB').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorDateInvalid').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorMissingAddress').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorMissingState').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorMissingCity').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorMissingPinCode').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorPinCodeInvalid').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorMissingEmail').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorEmailInvalid').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorStdCodeInvalid').innerHTML=""; 
 document.getElementById('errorPhoneNoInvalid').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorMissingMobileNo').innerHTML="";
 document.getElementById('errorMobileNoInvalid').innerHTML="";

}
```